# Is there anything I can do to speed up the synchronization of litecoinj?

Tags: litecoin, synchronization, bitcoinj, java, checkpoints

I am using [`litecoinj`](https://github.com/GENERALBYTESCOM/litecoinj) which is forked from `bitcoinj` but compared to `bitcoinj`, the wallet creation and block synching is slow when using `litecoinj`. So, I searched for a solution and found a post that suggests to download checkpoints in a file and pass the file while creating wallet, but I guess it's not working.

```
kit.setCheckpoints( new FileInputStream("checkpoints"));
```

How can I speed up the syncing of `litecoinj`?

Answer (score 0):

So after digging I got the solution, using this kit.setCheckpoints( new FileInputStream("checkpoints")); it was checking the file in the same package so to provide the exact path I have used 
kit.setCheckpoints( ReadProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("checkpoints"));